# Help with Integration with two functions

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

How to solve and speed up the following integration?

```
F[r_] := 1/(1 + (E^(2.13122 (-2.6 - r)) + 
        E^(2.13122 (-2.6 + r))) (1/2 + 0.0739645 r^2)^1.00384);
F[t_] := t^2/(1 + (E^(2.13122 (-2.6 - t)) + 
        E^(2.13122 (-2.6 + t))) (1/2 + 0.0739645 t^2)^1.00384);
F1[t_] := 12 Integrate[F[t], {t, 0, 10}];
FF[q_] := 12 Integrate[F[r]/F1[t]*Sin[q r]/(q r) r^2, {r, 0, 5}] 
    
    
Plot[FF[q], {q,2,20}]
```

Anyone know how to help or fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `NIntegrate`instead of `Integrate` because `F[t]` is numerical:

```
F[t_] := t^2/(1 + (E^(2.13122 (-2.6 - t)) + E^(2.13122 (-2.6 + t))) (1/2 + 0.0739645 t^2)^1.00384);
```

`F1[t]` doesn't  depend on t:

```
F1 = 12 NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 0, 10}] (*86.6488*)


FF[q_?NumericQ] :=12/F1 NIntegrate[F[r]  *Sin[q r]/(q r) r^2, {r, 0, 5}]
Plot[FF[q], {q, .001, 20 }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, All}[[-1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich Neumann. What does means `[[-1]]`?

Comment: You're welcome. `[[-1]]` gives the last element of a list! Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
F[r_] = 1/(1 + (E^(2.13122 (-2.6 - r)) + 
        E^(2.13122 (-2.6 + r))) (1/2 + 0.0739645 r^2)^1.00384);
g[t_] = t^2/F[t];
F1 = 12 NIntegrate[F[t], {t, 0, 10}];
FF[q_] := 12 NIntegrate[F[r]/F1*Sin[q r]/(q r) r^2, {r, 0, 5}]
Plot[FF[q], {q, 2, 20}]
```